# How to do editText like password

Tags: java, android, c

I want to do this code in c to Android
I dont use passwordtext
I need to use editText
ty

```
    ph=getch();
    if(ph!='\r'){
        pass[i]=ph;
printf("*");
```

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are doing. EditText is Java class for Android. What are you doing with C?

Comment: Please clarify your question so that we can help you.

Comment: i need this code in android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In xml of EditText iclude this attribute:

```
android:password="true"
```

If you want to do it in

Comment: Ty, but i need to do thes After a specific element

Comment: Post your code here.

Comment: i need after "," do password